# A laser with/of frequency 25THz? On/in the excited state?

Tags: prepositions

my major is physics, and now I am trying to write a paper about laser. My question is about the preposition choice. Should I use "a laser with frequency 25THz" or "a laser of frequency 25THz"? Should I use "an atom on the excited state" or "an atom in the excited state"? Thank you fo your help!

Comment: I suggest "a laser with **a** frequency **of** 25THz" and "an atom **in** the excited state".

Comment: I'm a technical writer who used to work in a laser lab decades ago - @WeatherVane has it exactly right in my opinion.

Comment: @GerardFalla I don't believe it is correct to use "the" referring to excited states. There is more than one excited state such that, IMO, it should be "an atom in _an_ excited state"

Comment: I happily stand corrected - well said!

Comment: @GerardFalla I checked the comment from PhotoScientist which improved on mine.

Comment: magnanimity in an SE comments section; I am truly impressed.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular usage, a laser is a device. What a laser produces is a coherent emission of photons. It is acceptable in everyday usage to refer to that emission alternately as a beam or laser beam, though your particular academic field may not accept the term laser beam. In everyday conversation you could say that you "saw a laser" or that something was "struck by a laser" but in academic circles this would be frowned upon. Consider, for example, that if your laser (device) were at a frequency of 25THz it would likely be vaporized by the amount of force used to make it vibrate that quickly.

The statement would, therefore, be most appropriate if phrased **"A laser with emission frequency of 25THz"** or "**A laser emission with frequency 25THz**"

Secondly, it is fairly uncommon to discuss atoms which are in an excited state since such atoms tend to release energy via a photon to return to the ground state. Atoms are therefore constantly being *promoted to* or *relaxing from* excited states and rarely *in* and excited state Nonetheless, if a particular atomic energy level is metastable then it will stay in an excited state.

Consider also, there is not just one excited state while there is only one ground state (n=1) so it would be appropriate to say "an atom in the ground state." However, it is more correct to say **"an atom in an excited state"** because there are multiple options or to specify the state such as **"an atom in the n=3 excited state"**

NB the difference is in the number of options such that am exclusive option is the option whereas a selective option is a/an option. Another example would be that you can drive your car at **a** speed of your choosing but you must stay below **the** speed limit.

Many sources such as this [wikipedia article on Rydberg Atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom) simply state "the excited atom" or "an excited atom" If I was writing the paper I would specify the excitation state the first time I discussed the atom (as above) and the simply refer to it as a/the excited atom thereafter.

Incidentally, There is still some debate over the term "laser" some say that it is an acronym and should therefore be "LASER" just as ATM or LAN. Others maintain that because laser is a [backronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym), it doesn't really matter. I was present at a function of the SPIE where someone asked [Charles Townes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Townes) for his opinion. He proposed that the device is really an optical oscillator rather than an optical amplifier and that the acronym should therefore be "LOSER." Perhaps that was his sense of humor, though, since Townes' 1950s notes refer to it as an "optical Maser."

Comment: The abbreviation of "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation" was **LASER**, the acronym is **laser**. There are plenty of other examples to be found, such as **SCUBA** - "Self-contained underwater breathing apparatus", now **scuba**.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! BTW, I failed to mention that what I consider is a two-level system, so "the excited state" is appropriate.

Comment: @WeatherVane agreed. I would never look twice at the word laser had I not heard Townes' objections to the term. It's off topic to ask here but is there rule or term for the "lower casing" of common acronyms? It seems to coincide with the loss of original meaning (few laypersons know what radar stands for) but I've only seen debate on the subject.

Comment: @JieyuYou that makes sense.  It would be correct to say "the excited state" in your case, though I would still define which state that is in your system at some point to avoid confusion. Perhaps the state in question is obvious, I.E. in the title of your paper :)

Comment: Isn't that the difference between an abbreviation and an acronym? **RADAR** was the abbreviation but **radar** is the acronym which has entered the language. I think it also depends on how you **say** it  - as its initials or as a word.

Comment: My point exactly. Technical writing class taught me that acronyms must be expanded once and capitalized always. Given that even the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) struggles to differentiate acronyms, abbreviations, and initializations, I doubt anyone could ever reach consensus. Maybe this topic is obscured by the fog of modern linguistic war.

Comment: You're both right—and wrong. It's both. At least according to Merriam-Webster.  (An abbreviation is one *type* of acronym.) An [acronym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym) is "a word (such as NATO, radar, or **laser**) formed from the initial letter or letters of each of the successive parts or major parts of a compound term; *also* : an abbreviation (such as *FBI*) formed from initial letters : INITIALISM" Regardless of terminology, it was *originally* LASER but has now become a ["proper word"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laser) in its own right without caps.